# How to make function like confirm

Tags: javascript

I want to make custom confirm function.

so, I make a code like :

```
function confirm(msg){
  var obj = document.createElement("div");
  var body = document.createElement("div");
  body.innerHTML = msg;

  var foot = document.createElement("div");

  var ok = document.createElement("div");
  ok.innerHTML = "OK";

  var cancel = document.createElement("div");
  cancel.innerHTML = "Cancel";

  foot.appendChild(ok);
  foot.appendChild(cancel);
  obj.appendChild(body);
  obj.appendChild(foot);

  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(obj);

  ok.onclick = function(){
    return true;
  }

  cancel.onclick = function(){
    return false;
  }
}
```

or

```
returnValue = -1;
ok.onclick = function(){
  returnValue = true;
}

canacel.onclick = function(){
  returnValue = false;
}

while(true){
  if(returnValue !== -1) break;
}

return returnValue;
```

If this custom confirm function must get 1 parameter like original confirm function.

How can make the custom confirm function?

Comment: You can not do sleeps in JavaScript so it is impossible to replace the confirm and have it pause execution until the user selects something. You would need to use callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use a [third-party dialog](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) already written for this, write a jQuery plugin, or at least take a more object-oriented approach. As it stands, you are putting a `confirm` function in the [global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted) (where a `confirm` function already exists).

Also note that you can't halt execution of the page and wait for a response like `window.confirm` can. See: [How can I reproduce the "wait" functionality provided by JavaScript's confirm() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822118/how-can-i-reproduce-the-wait-functionality-provided-by-javascripts-confirm) (where the accepted answer is "you can't").

The available way of performing such a task is to use a callback:

```
function customConfirm(message, resultCallback){

    ok.onclick = function(){

      // note that you can pass whatever you want to the callback
      // you are not limited to one parameter.
      resultCallback(true);
    }

    cancel.onclick = function(){
       resultCallback(false);
    }
}
```

In the above example, `resultCallback` is a function defined to perform an action(s) in response to events in your confirmation box.

You could pass an object with both the message and the callback to achieve the single parameter goal, but I suspect the real goal is to replace `window.confirm` which (as stated) behaves differently.

```
{ message: "foo", callback: function bar(status){ alert(status); } }
```

Comment: this custom confirm function must get 1 parameter

Comment: This custom confirm function must get 1 parameter, because It will be use CMS like wordpress or XpressEngine, other cms..
so, this custom confirm function must be able to use like original confirm function.

Comment: I see. So you are attempting to *replace* the default `window.confirm` function?

Comment: Yes, I try that.but I was failed

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to truly halt execution like `window.confirm` does and wait for a return value. Certainly, a busy loop (`while(true)`) will not accomplish your goal.

Comment: I make alert function already..
but, i can't make confirm..

ok, i just give up now;

Answer (score 1):

You can't have your `confirm` function halt until a value is found, otherwise the whole page would freeze. What you need in this case is to provide a **callback** to execute once either of the buttons is clicked (if you can not pass it as argument for any reason, you'd have to use a global var, or maybe a queue):

```
var queue = [];
function confirm(msg){
  ...
  var callback = queue.shift();
  ok.onclick = function(){
    callback(true);
  }

  cancel.onclick = function(){
    callback(false);
  }
}
```

You use it this way:

```
queue.push(function(returnValue) {
    if ( returnValue ) {
       // Code for "yes"
    }
    else {
       // Code for "no"
    }
});
confirm("Are you sure?");
```

Comment: this custom confirm function must get 1 parameter

Comment: @user2128228 I modified my answer so you can call it with one argument, but now it requires a separate step to add the callback. If you want it to return the needed value, you're out of luck - there's no way to do that with JavaScript, since the page will lock until your code finishes executing (it won't even show your newly created DOM elements in the page until then).

Answer (score 1):

like my case i used promise to solve the delete confirmation problem, here is the code

```
function deleteBook(id, elm) {
const container_alert = document.querySelector('.container-alert') 
 
alertMsg('Anda yakin ingin menghapus?').then(() => {
        // console.log('i love you');
        let index = books.findIndex(book => book.id == id);
        books.splice(index, 1)
        updateDataToStorage();
        elm.parentNode.parentNode.remove()
        
        container_alert.classList.add('hidden')
}).catch(() => {
    container_alert.classList.add('hidden')
})
```

}

and my alert function code is as follows

```
function alertMsg(msg) {
const container_alert = document.querySelector('.container-alert') 
const btn_yes = document.querySelector('.action-alert .yes')
const btn_cancel = document.querySelector('.action-alert .cancel')

container_alert.classList.remove('hidden')

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    btn_yes.addEventListener('click', function(){
        resolve()  
    })

    btn_cancel.addEventListener('click', function(){
        reject()
    })
})
```

}